# Display username from login to other page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple login page (login_page.html). The farmerId (= user name) which is used for the login, should be displayed on the next page (after login), which is the farmer.html + farmer.js
I tried it as followed, but the farmerId/user name is not displaying at the farmer page.

***changed to minimal reproducible example  ***

**testlog.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <script defer src="testlog.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="login-form" action="testfarmer.html">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="FarmerID"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="login-form-submit();"/>
    </form>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

**testlog.js**

```
function login-form-submit()
{
  var farmerID=document.getElementById("username-field").value;
  localStorage.setItem("id", farmerID);
  return false;
}
```

**testfarmer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Farmer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testfarmer.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    FarmerID <span id="farmer"></span>          
</body>

</html>
```

**testfarmer.js**

```
document.getElementById("farmer").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("id");
```

Does someone has any suggestion, where my problem could be?

Comment: If the pages come from same origin, then your code should work. Look in the console for errors

Comment: Thanks. Console says that in farmer.js  `document.getElementByid (....) is null`  I went trough the code, but I can't see a mistake ....

Comment: Perhaps you execute the code before the span exists - please make a [mcve]

Comment: @Kate then show your `farmer.html` and `farmer.js`

Comment: @MijanurRahaman the last two codes in my question are the farmer.html and farmer.js

Comment: @mplungjan I tried it with a minimal reproductible example (thanks for the tip) - I also changed the code in the question to this. Unfortunately it is still not working (the username/farmerID doesnt't display on the second page (testfarmer.html) - perhaps there is a small mistake, which I overlook right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, as @mplungjan suggested, the execution was wrong.
This is the corrected html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Farmer</title>  
</head>

<body>
    FarmerID <span id="farmer"></span> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testfarmer.js"></script>           
</body>

</html>
```

If the link for testfarmer.js is in the head, it is not executing correct.This is why I put it direct under the  element